# How do I share a label value between multiple CruiseControl.NET builds?

Tags: build, build-automation, cruisecontrol.net, versioning, ccnet-config

I have two projects set up in CruiseControl.NET: CI build and nightly build.

Both of them execute the same NAnt script, but with different parameters.

The CruiseControl.NET label (currently generated by the *DefaultLabeler*) is embedded into AssemblyInfo as the build part of the version (for example, *MajorVersion.MinorVersion.CCNET_Label.SVN_Revision*).

For more consistent versioning I would like both projects to share the same CruiseControl.NET label value.

I have investigated the labelers that are available as part of the CruiseControl.NET installation, but I could not find one that does what I want.

How do I share a label value between multiple CruiseControl.NET builds? 
If there is a better way to do this, I would like to know.

I found a way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could not find an existing solution that to do what I needed, so I ended up writing a custom CruiseControl.NET labeller.

Here's how it is done:

1. Create a new project. This will be used as a plugin library by CC.NET
2. The name of the output DLL needs to match *ccnet.\*.CruiseControl.plugin*. Go to project 
   properties and change "Assembly name" to *ccnet.<insert name here>.CruiseControl.plugin*
3. In your project, add references to the three assemblies found in the CC.NET server installation directory (default is: C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server):

   - NetReflector.dll
   - ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.dll
   - ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.dll
4. Create a new public class such as this:

   ```
   using ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core;
   using ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote;

   // this is the labeller name that will be used in  ccnet.config
   [ReflectorType("customLabeller")]
   public class CustomLabeller : ILabeller
   {
    [ReflectorProperty("syncronisationFilePath", Required = true)]
    public string SyncronisationFilePath { get; set; }

    #region ILabeller Members

    public string Generate(IIntegrationResult previousResult)
    {
     if (ShouldIncrementLabel(previousResult))
      return IncrementLabel();

     if (previousResult.Status == IntegrationStatus.Unknown)
      return "0";

     return previousResult.Label;
    }

    public void Run(IIntegrationResult result)
    {
     result.Label = Generate(result);
    }

    #endregion

    private string IncrementLabel()
    {
     if(!File.Exists(SyncronisationFilePath))
      return "0";

     using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(SyncronisationFilePath,
          FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
          FileAccess.ReadWrite,
          FileShare.None))
      {
       // read last build number from file
       var bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
       fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

       string rawBuildNumber = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

       // parse last build number
       int previousBuildNumber = int.Parse(rawBuildNumber);
       int newBuildNumber = previousBuildNumber + 1;

       // increment build number and write back to file
       bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newBuildNumber.ToString());

       fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

       return newBuildNumber.ToString();
      }
    }

    private static bool ShouldIncrementLabel(IIntegrationResult previousResult)
    {
     return (previousResult.Status == IntegrationStatus.Success ||
       previousResult.Status == IntegrationStatus.Unknown)
    }
   }
   ```
5. Compile your project and copy the DLL to CC.NET server installation directory (default is: C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server)
6. Restart CC.NET Windows service
7. Create a text file to store the current build number
8. Add the new labeler to you project definition in ccnet.config file:

   ```
       <labeller type="sharedLabeller">
           <syncronisationFilePath>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\shared\buildnumber.txt</syncronisationFilePath>
   <incrementOnFailure>false</incrementOnFailure>
       </labeller>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, but I found that using the `<stateFileLabeller>` in conjunction with the `<assemblyVersionLabeller>` proved to be a much simpler solution.

The only gotcha about using the stateFileLabeller is that you can't specify a directory for your state files in a project, because CruiseControl.NET won't find it. I left it in the default directory, and it works great.

Answer (score 3):

I've modified the class Arnold made making it more of a replica of the defaultlabeller:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

using Exortech.NetReflector;
using ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core;
using ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote;

// This namespace could be altered and several classes could be put into the same if you'd want to combine several plugins in one dll
namespace ccnet.SharedLabeller.CruiseControl.plugin
{
    [ReflectorType("sharedLabeller")]
    public class SharedLabeller : ILabeller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The path where the file that holds the shared label should be located
        /// </summary>
        /// <default>none</default>
        [ReflectorProperty("sharedLabelFilePath", Required = true)]
        public string SharedLabelFilePath { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Any string to be put in front of all labels.
        /// </summary>
        [ReflectorProperty("prefix", Required = false)]
        public string Prefix { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// If true, the label will be incremented even if the build fails. Otherwise it will only be incremented if the build succeeds.
        /// </summary>
        [ReflectorProperty("incrementOnFailure", Required = false)]
        public bool IncrementOnFailure { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// If false, the label will never be incremented when this project is builded. This is usefull for deployment builds that
        /// should use the last successfull of two or more builds
        /// </summary>
        [ReflectorProperty("increment", Required = false)]
        public bool Increment { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows you to set the initial build number.
        /// This will only be used when on the first build of a project, meaning that when you change this value,
        /// you'll have to stop the CCNet service and delete the state file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <default>0</default>
        [ReflectorProperty("initialBuildLabel", Required = false)]
        public int InitialBuildLabel { get; set; }

        public SharedLabeller()
        {
            IncrementOnFailure = false;
            Increment = true;
            InitialBuildLabel = 0;
        }

        #region ILabeller Members

        public string Generate(IIntegrationResult integrationResult)
        {
            if (ShouldIncrementLabel(integrationResult.LastIntegration))
            {
                return Prefix + this.GetLabel();
            }
            else
            {
                return integrationResult.LastIntegration.Label;
            }
        }

        public void Run(IIntegrationResult integrationResult)
        {
            integrationResult.Label = Generate(integrationResult);
        }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Get and increments the label, unless increment is false then it only gets the label
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GetLabel()
        {
            ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Util.Log.Debug("About to read label file. Filename: {0}", SharedLabelFilePath);
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(this.SharedLabelFilePath,
                     FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                     FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                     FileShare.None))
            {
                // Read last build number from file
                var bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                string rawBuildNumber = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                // Parse last build number
                int previousBuildNumber;
                if (!int.TryParse(rawBuildNumber, out previousBuildNumber))
                {
                    previousBuildNumber = InitialBuildLabel - 1;
                }

                if (!Increment)
                {
                    return previousBuildNumber.ToString();
                }

                int newBuildNumber = previousBuildNumber + 1;

                // Increment build number and write back to file
                bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newBuildNumber.ToString());

                fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                return newBuildNumber.ToString();
            }
        }

        private bool ShouldIncrementLabel(IntegrationSummary integrationSummary)
        {
            return integrationSummary == null || integrationSummary.Status == IntegrationStatus.Success || IncrementOnFailure;
        }
    }
}
```

The benefit should be that you now can specify prefix as well as "incrementonfailure". Also I've added a "increment" property that can be used for deployment builds that should not increment the build number at all. If you want to modify it yourself I would advise to have a look at their implementations:
[CruiseControl.NET repository folder containing labellers](https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/tree/master/project/core/label)