# Globally increment the Last Build Label across multiple CruiseControl.NET projects

Tags: mercurial, cruisecontrol.net, versioning, label

We use CruiseControl.NET to automate our builds and keep track of the Last Build Number.   However, this number resets to one for newly created CC.NET projects.  We would like the Last Build Number sequence to continue for branched projects (e.g., patches to existing releases).

Is there a way to globally increment the Last Build Label across multiple CruiseControl.NET projects?

Comment: You can create a custom labeller plugin yourself. Here is an example I believe could solve your problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706601/how-do-i-share-a-label-value-between-multiple-cc-net-builds/16585872#16585872

Answer (score 1):

Th build number is kept in the project's state file. If you branch, take the build number from the original project's state file and put it into the one of the branch project (or copy the state file and make the necessary edits like file name, project name etc.). Since the state files are XML this should be easy enough to do programmatically if  your branch process is script-based.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe that the build number will still increase independently for each project.  Rather, I wanted to share the build number across projects and have any project's build increment the same number.